# Nested Json in list of Map

Tags: apex

```
{
"RecordCount": 2,
"ProspectActivities": [
    {
        "Id": "3f4fffc2-f82f-11e6-8e85-22000b084956",
        "EventCode": 30,
        "EventName": "Sales Activity",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Key": "Currency",
                "Value": "$"
            },
            {
                "Key": "OrderValue",
                "Value": "0"
            },
            {
                "Key": "SalesData",
                "Value": "{keyvalueinfo}"
            }             
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "3f4fffc2-f82f-11e6-8e85-22000b084956",
        "EventCode": 30,
        "EventName": "Call",
        "Data": [
            {
                "Key": "Duration",
                "Value": "22"
            },
            {
                "Key": "Caller",
                "Value": "Abhi"
            }             
        ]
    }
 }
```

For this JSON response, how can I create a `List<Map<String,String>>` where:

- each map contains 1 record
- 1 record will have key and value as following:

---

```
"Id": "3f4fffc2-f82f-11e6-8e85-22000b084956",
    "EventCode": 30,
    "Currency" : "$",
    "SalesData":" "{keyvalueinfo}"
```

Comment: You can deserialize it to wrapper and iterate over list. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying but as i am new to it, so getting some difficulties. Could you please share the code, how i could achieve it? @RahulSharma

Comment: Your post does not contain a question. Please [edit] it to contain one, and make explicit what the problem is. Do you get an error? If so please include it here ***verbatim***.

Comment: You should read the `JSON` class [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm). There's a good exemple of deserialization within a `Map` using the `deserializeUntyped(jsonString)` method.

Comment: I have tried but not getting it in the format i need as i mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1):

I'd look through [this question and answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17549/invalid-conversion-from-runtime-type-listany-to-mapstring-any) . You can create a class and deserialize into that class.

I generated this using [JSON2Apex](https://www.adminbooster.com/tool/json2apex)

```
public class fromJSON{
    public Integer RecordCount; //2
    public cls_ProspectActivities[] ProspectActivities;
    class cls_ProspectActivities {
        public String Id;   //3f4fffc2-f82f-11e6-8e85-22000b084956
        public Integer EventCode;   //30
        public String EventName;    //Sales Activity
        public cls_Data[] Data;
    }
    class cls_Data {
        public String Key;  //Currency
        public String Value;    //$
    }
    public static fromJSON parse(String json){
        return (fromJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(json, fromJSON.class);
    }

    static testMethod void testParse() {
        String json=        '{'+
        '"RecordCount": 2,'+
        '"ProspectActivities": ['+
        '    {'+
        '        "Id": "3f4fffc2-f82f-11e6-8e85-22000b084956",'+
        '        "EventCode": 30,'+
        '        "EventName": "Sales Activity",'+
        '        "Data": ['+
        '            {'+
        '                "Key": "Currency",'+
        '                "Value": "$"'+
        '            },'+
        '            {'+
        '                "Key": "OrderValue",'+
        '                "Value": "0"'+
        '            },'+
        '            {'+
        '                "Key": "SalesData",'+
        '                "Value": "{keyvalueinfo}"'+
        '            }             '+
        '        ]'+
        '    },'+
        '    {'+
        '        "Id": "3f4fffc2-f82f-11e6-8e85-22000b084956",'+
        '        "EventCode": 30,'+
        '        "EventName": "Call",'+
        '        "Data": ['+
        '            {'+
        '                "Key": "Duration",'+
        '                "Value": "22"'+
        '            },'+
        '            {'+
        '                "Key": "Caller",'+
        '                "Value": "Abhi"'+
        '            }             '+
        '        ]'+
        '    }'+
        ']'+
        ' }';
        fromJSON obj = parse(json);
        System.assert(obj != null);
    }
}
```

From there you should be able to deserialize by using the  parse(String json) method.

Comment: This is not really an answer, I would recommend you extract the relevant parts of the link (those that apply to the OP) and post them here instead.

Comment: edited with more detail