# Getting error while writing test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, httpcalloutmock

When i am trying to write a test class for my class (NameProjectTDfromAccolade).. I am getting the below error 
    System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List to Map on line number 45.

The class is working with the existing code , it is not throwing any error but when i am trying to write a test class
    for that it is throwing error.

Can anyone suggest me how to fix this?

Error:

> System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List< ANY>
>   to Map< String, ANY> on line number 45.

Class:

```
public class NameProjectTDfromAccolade {

    public Map<String,String> UpdateNameTDfromAcc(String ProjectID){
      List<String> codes= new List<String>();
        system.debug('ProjectID'+ProjectID);
      AccSetting1__c accolade = AccSetting1__c.getorgDefaults();
                HTTP h = new HTTP();
                HTTPRequest r = new HTTPRequest();
                Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(accolade.UserName__c + ':' + accolade.Password_del__c);
                 String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
                r.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
                r.setMethod('GET');
                r.setTimeout(120000);
        String baseEndPoint = 'Endpoint URl';// i have removed this URL for security 
               r.setEndpoint(baseEndPoint);
               HTTPResponse resp = new HTTPResponse();
               resp = h.send(r);
               system.debug('@@@'+resp.getbody());
               String result=resp.getbody();

  List<Object> lst_JsonParse = (List<Object>)Json.deserializeUntyped(result);
Map<String, Object> m0 = (Map<String, Object>)lst_JsonParse[0];
Map<String, Object> m1 = (Map<String, Object>)lst_JsonParse[1];
Map<String, Object> m2 = (Map<String, Object>)lst_JsonParse[2];
//system.debug('map '+m);
Integer leftProjectId0 = (Integer)m0.get('leftProjectId');
Integer leftProjectId1 = (Integer)m1.get('leftProjectId');
Integer leftProjectId2 = (Integer)m2.get('leftProjectId');

AccSetting1__c accolade0 = AccSetting1__c.getorgDefaults();
                HTTP ht0 = new HTTP();
                HTTPRequest re0 = new HTTPRequest();
                Blob headerValuee0 = Blob.valueOf(accolade0.UserName__c + ':' + accolade0.Password_del__c);
                 String authorizationHeaderr0 = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValuee0);
                re0.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeaderr0);
                re0.setMethod('GET');
                re0.setTimeout(120000);

String baseEndPointf0 = 'Endpoint URl(leftProjectId0)';// i have removed this URL 
               re0.setEndpoint(baseEndPointf0);
               HTTPResponse respp0 = new HTTPResponse();
               respp0 = ht0.send(re0);
               system.debug('@@@'+respp0.getbody());
  String resultt0=respp0.getbody();
Map<String, Object> mm0 = (Map<String, Object>)
      JSON.deserializeUntyped(resultt0);
system.debug('map0 '+mm0);
String codee0 = (String)mm0.get('code');
        String namee0 = (String)mm0.get('name');
system.debug('code,name of TD'+codee0+namee0);


AccSetting1__c accolade1 = AccSetting1__c.getorgDefaults();
                HTTP ht1 = new HTTP();
                HTTPRequest re1 = new HTTPRequest();
                Blob headerValuee1 = Blob.valueOf(accolade1.UserName__c + ':' + accolade1.Password_del__c);
                 String authorizationHeaderr1 = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValuee1);
                re1.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeaderr1);
                re1.setMethod('GET');
                re1.setTimeout(120000);

String baseEndPointf1 = 'Endpoint URl(leftProjectId0)';// i have removed this URL 
               re1.setEndpoint(baseEndPointf1);
               HTTPResponse respp1 = new HTTPResponse();
               respp1 = ht1.send(re1);
               system.debug('@@@'+respp1.getbody());
  String resultt1=respp1.getbody();
Map<String, Object> mm1 = (Map<String, Object>)
      JSON.deserializeUntyped(resultt1);
system.debug('map1 '+mm1);
String codee1 = (String)mm1.get('code');
        String namee1 = (String)mm1.get('name');

system.debug('code,name of TD'+codee1+namee1);

Map<String,String> finalCodeName = new Map<String,String>();

if(codee0.left(4)=='P-IC'){
       finalCodeName.put('code' ,codee0);
       finalCodeName.put('name' ,namee0);
        }else if(codee1.left(4)=='P-IC'){

         finalCodeName.put('code' ,codee1);
       finalCodeName.put('name' ,namee1);
        }
         system.debug('finalCodeName'+finalCodeName);
    return finalCodeName;

    }    

}
```

test class:

```
@istest
public class NameProjectTDfromAccolade_test {

 @isTest static void testCallout() {
      NameProjectTDfromAccolade accol = new NameProjectTDfromAccolade();          
  StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
  mock.setStaticResource('Comments');
  mock.setStatusCode(200);
  mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');      
       Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
     Map<String,Object> res= accol.UpdateNameTDfromAcc('9726');

    }


}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion- naming conventions in your code don't make any sense at all, in fact they are very confusing. Give logical names to your variables, methods, and classes, etc.

Comment: looks like the Jsons format is is List, not a map. log `resultt0` before you cast it, to find out what it does here:
`Map<String, Object> mm0 = (Map<String, Object>)
      JSON.deserializeUntyped(resultt0);`

Comment: Yes Just now i have debugged my code . It is List not Map

Answer (score 0):

**1-Edit your class**

Replace your line 45

```
Map<String, Object> mm0 = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(resultt0);
```

With the following

```
Map<String, Object> mm0 = new Map< String, Object >( (List <Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(resultt0) );
```

Possible reason: I am not sure what is in `result0` but it appears that the results are returned as `List<Object>` instead of a `map`.

**Workaround**(as suggested by other users in related [questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17549/invalid-conversion-from-runtime-type-listany-to-mapstring-any))

if the response is known, and the fields are not going to change use something like below to have more concrete results

```
public class MockResponse{
  public String code;
  public String Name;
}
...
List<MockResponse> responseList = (List<MockResponse>)JSON.deserialize(resultt0.getBody(), MockResponse.class);
```

**2- Edit your test class**

Edit your test class and replace

`Map<String,Object> res= accol.UpdateNameTDfromAcc('9726');`

with

`Map<String,String> res= accol.UpdateNameTDfromAcc('9726');`

As the method signature `UpdateNameTDfromAcc()` in your test class is returning `Map<String, String>` not `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: yes it is a list not Map. i am getting the below error when i am trying to use the code which you have given

Comment: Invalid initializer type List<Object> found for Map<String,Object>: expected a Map with the same key and value types, or a valid SObject List

Comment: result0={"access":11111,"code":"P-IC-111111111","createdById":12345,"createdDate":"2016-05-24","currentName":"G1: Lab Development Gate", "name":"XYZ"}

Comment: Replace the `Object` in the code with your custom object API name. I am assuming it to be `Project__c` but you should use the actual one.

Comment: @Spyder : updated my answer, please check again.

Comment: Thanks for your Quick response . I have made the changes in my code as you mentioned but still it is getting the same errror

Comment: Note that you can get `<ol>` formatting using `1.` rather than `1-`.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't really looking to do formatting here. I was more inclined towards letting OP know, what number of changes he needs to make. :)